# select rows greater and smaller than two numbers with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe as following,

```
id     price
01      10
02      5
03      0.1
04      100
05      1000
```

How could I get a new dataframe containing only price greater than $10 (including) and smaller than $100 (including) like this. Thanks.

```
id     price
01      10
04      100
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['price'].between(10, 100)]
print (df)
   id  price
0   1   10.0
3   4  100.0
```

If dont need include values `10` and `100`:

```
df = df[df['price'].between(10, 100, inclusive=False)]
```

Comment: Thanks. what if 10 and 100 not including, how can i deal with it?

Comment: @ahbon df['price'].between(10,100)] just returns True or False for each row depending on whether they fulfill the condition. Then you use this as argument for df[] to pick out the row between 10 and 100. To get the opposite, you just invert the bools, i.e. df[~df['price'].between(10,100)] -- note the ~